# How to position the button right side of textbox?

Tags: html, css, button, position

I want to position my button on the right side using CSS.

here's the script:

```
<input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Location" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 10px; width: 30%; z-index: 1;">

<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.reload();" style="width: 10%; margin-top: 10px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #dce4ec; color: #2c3e50" value="Refresh" />

<div id="map" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: the button is all ready at right side...!!

Comment: It's already in right side only right side means to right extreme corner?

Comment: Paul, it's already on the right side. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWJRgg

Comment: Adding proper tags improves the chance of getting your answered

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.search-form input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-form">
<input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Location" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 10px; width: 30%; z-index: 1;">

<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.reload();" style="width: 10%; margin-top: 10px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #dce4ec; color: #2c3e50" value="Refresh" />
</div>
<div id="map" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all into one container and position the container, then add width to both to be equal 100%:

```
<style>
.container {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 100px;
}
.container #search {
width:80%;
}
.container .btn {
width:20%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Location">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.reload();" value="Refresh" />
</div>
```

or, if you use bootstrap3, just follow this link:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main{
width:300px;
height:25px;
position:relative;
}
.button{
position:absolute;
right:-75px;
top:0px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div class="main">
<input type="text" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Search Here"/>
<button type="reset" class="button">Refresh</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Try It Once